# Creating Junit Test With IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

When I try to create a Junit test for certain classes in my project nothing happens when I hit OK. IntelliJ also doesn't give me the option to select a destination folder. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to open the same project on another IDE (I suggest NetBeans) and try to make the same operation. It could be some mistake at method visibility

Comment: I have given the exact steps to do this, please follow you will overcome the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is pretty simple . Just right click on the desired Folder -> Mark Directory as -> Test Source Root

Now for any Code, just right click on the class -> Go to -> Test -> Create New test .

Now click Ok, you will the test is created in the folder which you have marked as test Source Root.

Comment: Thank you so much @Biraj B Choudhury. It's really helpful for me.